# Google Extension: Access to DOM in iframe of a different domain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

So I've found several pages on here, as well as various blog posts that seem to do pretty much exactly what I want to do, but they are all a few years old and seem really easy but don't work.

As the title says, On thisdomain.com there is a iframe from thatdomain.com and I want to get the value in a div in that iframe.

Manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 1,
    "name": "MyExtention",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Nothing Yet",
    "permissions": [
          "storage",
          "tabs",
          "unlimitedStorage",
          "webRequest",
          "webNavigation",
          "*://*.match-both-iframe-and-main-domain.com/*",
          "*://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["listener.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "content_scripts": 
    [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.matchnothing.shshdjdjffkdj.com/*"],
            "js": ["mainscript.js"],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ]
}
```

The content script url matches nothing because it is fired from a listener (which works).  Basically it waits for a request from one of 2 urls before it activates.

listener.js

```
var chrome = chrome || {};
var callback = function(listenerRes) {
    console.log(listenerRes.url);
    if (listenerRes.url.indexOf("listenurl1") > -1 ||
        listenerRes.url.indexOf("listenurl2") > -1) {
        chrome.tabs.get(listenerRes.tabId, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "mainscript.js"});
        });
    }
};

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( callback, {urls: ["*://*.google.com/*"]} );
```

mainscript.js

```
var chrome = chrome || {};

   ... // helper functions and such

var iframe = document.getElementsByid('myiframe'); 


// Get all data.
var datas = [];
try {
   datas = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('mydata'); // error is here
}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}

...  // do stuff with the data
```

On the commented line it throws a "Blocked a frame with origin URL from accessing a cross-origin frame."

So I am under the impression that some combination of all_frames = true, the chrome.tabs.executeScript, and the domains in the permissions should allow for this to work.  But it doesn't.

It might be important to note, the reason for this listener is because the iframe isnt on the page to start.

Please help, Im an experienced web developer but this is my 1st foray into Chrome Extentions.

Comment: `executeScript` doesn't use `manifest.json`. Instead see what `allFrames: true` parameter of `executeScript` does and use it. Maybe you can elaborate on what you want to do with the iframe data so that a complete answer can be given?

Comment: Ill check that tonight.

As for what Im doing with the data, I'm not sure it relevant in this case because I cant even get to the data.  However, I'm getting some text from a div, sending it to a 3rd party, and inserting the response into another div

Comment: I tried you're suggestion to no avail.  :(

Comment: Can you edit the question and the new code in the end?